# Exercise 3 point (g) in Stanley Combinatorics volume 1 chapter 1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm having a hard time understanding the solution of the exercise 3 point (g) of Stanley Combinatorics volume 1 chapter 1. This exercise basically asks to prove in a combinatorial way the following equality
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 x^k=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\binom{2n-j}{n}(x-1)^j.$$
The author's solution is the following:

- The LHS term is the number of ways to choose a triple $(S,T,f:S\to [x])$ such that $S\subseteq [n]$, $T\subseteq [n+1,2n]$ and $|S|=|T|$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of such triples.
- The RHS term is the number of ways to choose a triple $(A,B,g:A\to [x-1])$ such that $A\subseteq [n]$ and $B$ is a $n$-subset of $[2n]-A$. Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the set of such triples.

I agree with these observations. Then the author constructs a bijection between $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ as follows
$$(S,T,f)\mapsto (f^{-1}[x-1],([n]-S)\cup T,f|_{f^{-1}[x-1]}).$$
I agree that this is a well defined map, but after wrapping my mind around this a little bit I couldn't construct the inverse map or prove that this map is a bijection and the author doesn't justify this any further. Could you help me?

Starting from $(A,B,g)$ if we could extrapolate $S$, then finding $T$ and $f$ would be easy, because $T$ would be simply $B-([n]-S)$ and $f$ would be simply the map such that $f|_A=g, \ f|_{S-A}=x$. I know that I should use the fact that $|S|=|T|$ but I don't know how. This exercise just feels artificial and convoluted to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not used the specific conditions on $S$ and $T$ that $S\subset [n],T\subset [n+1,2n]$.

As you mentioned, the problem lies in finding $S$. If that is done, then the rest is easy. We have the set $B \subset [2n]-A\subset [2n]$.
We know that $T\subset [n+1,2n]$. Therefore, $[n]-S=B \cap [n]$. This implies that $S=[n]-(B\cap [n])$.

Comment: Thank you so much